# When a user clicks on either button I'd like for the name of the location to fadeIn but I'm not able to get it to work with this conditional statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a user clicks on either button I'd like for the name of the location to fadeIn but I'm not able to get it to work with this conditional statement. I have a "Next" and a "Previous" button.
I was thinking by referencing the current element using e.target I could fadeIn() the extra information in my  elements relevant to to each specific picture when the user clicks over to that picture

```
HTML

 <div class="divs">
       <div id="motion1"><img class="motion" src="./c1.jpg"><span class="info">Copacabana</span></div>
        <div><img id="motion2" class ="motion" src="./c2.jpg"><span class="info">Ipanema</span></div>
       <div><img id="motion3" class="motion" src="./c3.jpg"><span class="info">Florianópolis</span></div>
        <div><img id ="motion4" class="motion" src="./c4.jpg"><span class="info">Jericoacoara</span></div>
        <div><img id="motion5" class="motion" src="./c5.jpg"><span class="info">Praia da Trindade</span></div>
       <div><img id="motion6" class="motion" src="./c6.jpg"><span class="info">Porto de Galinhas</span></div>

      
    </div>
```

```
$(function() {

    $(".divs div:not('#motion1')").hide();
    let $span = $("span");
    $span.hide();
```

THIS IT THE CONDITIONAL STATEMENT ATTACHED THE CLICK EVENT IN QUESTION

```
$("#button2").on("click", function(e) {
    let target = e.target;
    if ($(this) == target) {
        $span.fadeIn();
    }
})
```

Comment: `let $span = $("span");` is a too common selector. Be more specific.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Titles are not meant to describe your problem, but to present in a short sentence your main issue. Please read [ask], then [edit] with a [mcve].

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I added a class attribute to the span but it's still not working

Comment: `if ($(this) == target) {` what do you think this line should do? Have you tried to `console.log($(this))` and `console.log(e.target)`? Do you know that e.target can give you false positives? Please share some HTML, CSS, and the minimal JS to reflect and reproduce the problem. Explain what you're actually after. In this state the question is incomprehensible.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I apologize for the confusion. I'm fairly new to stack. I just edited the question and some of the code. I hope that's more useful.

Comment: Why your first DIV has an ID but the other don't? Why your fist image doesn't have an ID but all the other images do?

Comment: What should `$span.fadeIn();` do? Can you explain? `$span` are all SPAN element on your document...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand from your explanation. You want to show the related info inside the span which belongs to the picture that is clicked.

Here is an example code produced from your code to showcase this. Check it out if this is what you want.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset = "UTF-8">
   <title>----</title>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".divs div:not('#motion1')").hide();
       let $span = $(".info");
      $span.hide();
      $(".motion").on("click", function(e) 
          {
             
             //console.log($(this).parent())
             $(".info").hide();
             $(this).parent().children("span").fadeIn()
        })
    });
    </script>
    
  </head>

  <body>
  <div class="divs">
      <div id="motion1"><img class="motion" src="./c1.jpg"><span     class="info">Copacabana</span></div>
      <div><img id="motion2" class ="motion" src="./c2.jpg"><span class="info">Ipanema</span></div>
      <div><img id="motion3" class="motion" src="./c3.jpg"><span class="info">Florianópolis</span></div>
      <div><img id ="motion4" class="motion" src="./c4.jpg"><span class="info">Jericoacoara</span></div>
      <div><img id="motion5" class="motion" src="./c5.jpg"><span class="info">Praia da Trindade</span></div>
      <div><img id="motion6" class="motion" src="./c6.jpg"><span class="info">Porto de Galinhas</span></div>
  
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: that's exactly what I needed! much appreciated. Any suggestions on courses or books or how I can speed up my learning curve as I self taught developer? I've been following books for a year and as far as i've come along I still feel like I should be way further

Comment: I'm glad it's useful for you. Nothing much to say really. I generally look through w3schools javascript / jquery content. Reproduce as much as example you can. if you want speed up or have a more intense learning process, you could consider paid course on udemy, stackskills or other  similar websites.  But in the end,  more you practice more you retain.

Comment: Will continue to do so, respect and all the best to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want if I understand your question correctly.

1. I will move `.motion` to both `img`'s & `span.info`'s parent element so it is easily to choose `img` and their `.info` by `this`.
2. `show` function will only show 1 picture depend on `i`.
3. `$('.motion').on('click' ...` will show & hide `.info` when user click `img`.
4. `$('button').on('click' ...` will switch `img` and `.info`.

```js
function show(i) {
  $(`.motion:nth-of-type(${i})`).show()
  $(`.motion:not(:nth-of-type(${i}))`).hide()
}

let img_num = 1
let motion_len = $('.motion').length
$(() => {
  $('.info').hide()
  show(img_num)
  $('.motion').on('click', function() {
    $('.info', this).fadeToggle()
  })
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    $('.info').hide()
    let btn = $(this).attr('class')
    if (btn === 'next') {
      img_num += 1
    } else if (btn === 'previous') {
      img_num -= 1
    }
    img_num = img_num < 1 ? 6 : img_num > 6 ? 1 : img_num
    show(img_num)
  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="motion"><img src="./c1.jpg"><span class="info">Copacabana</span></div>
  <div class="motion"><img src="./c2.jpg"><span class="info">Ipanema</span></div>
  <div class="motion"><img src="./c3.jpg"><span class="info">Florianópolis</span></div>
  <div class="motion"><img src="./c4.jpg"><span class="info">Jericoacoara</span></div>
  <div class="motion"><img src="./c5.jpg"><span class="info">Praia da Trindade</span></div>
  <div class="motion"><img src="./c6.jpg"><span class="info">Porto de Galinhas</span></div>
  <button class="previous">Previous</button>
  <button class="next">Next</button>
</div>
```